# How to map elements of array to every record in a Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on a dataframe that looks like this -

```
val df = Seq(
(0.0  ),
(0.0  ),
(0.0  ),
(0.317),
(0.0  ),
(0.0  ),
(-0.78),
(-0.37),
(0.0  ),
(0.0  ),
(0.0  ),
(0.0  )
).toDF("importance")
```

I now have some more code to get `labels` and `features` columns as arrays as shown below -

```
val labels = Array(0,1,2)
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit
val df1 = df.withColumn("labels", typedLit(labels))
val featureNames = Array("a","b","c","d")
val df2 = df1.withColumn("features", typedLit(featureNames))

scala> df2.show(false)
+----------+---------+------------+
|importance|labels   |features    |
+----------+---------+------------+
|0.0       |[0, 1, 2]|[a, b, c, d]|
|0.0       |[0, 1, 2]|[a, b, c, d]|
|0.0       |[0, 1, 2]|[a, b, c, d]|
|0.317     |[0, 1, 2]|[a, b, c, d]|
|0.0       |[0, 1, 2]|[a, b, c, d]|
|0.0       |[0, 1, 2]|[a, b, c, d]|
|-0.78     |[0, 1, 2]|[a, b, c, d]|
|-0.37     |[0, 1, 2]|[a, b, c, d]|
|0.0       |[0, 1, 2]|[a, b, c, d]|
|0.0       |[0, 1, 2]|[a, b, c, d]|
|0.0       |[0, 1, 2]|[a, b, c, d]|
|0.0       |[0, 1, 2]|[a, b, c, d]|
+----------+---------+------------+
```

Now, using this dataframe I want to align each value of importance column with each element of `labels` and `features` arrays. So the output should look something like this -

```
label feature name  importance
0         a             0      
0         b             0      
0         c             0      
0         d             0.3176 
1         a             0      
1         b             0      
1         c             -0.78  
1         d             -0.37  
2         a             0      
2         b             0      
2         c             0      
2         d             0
```

So first record has `label=0` and `feature=a` and has an `importance = 0`.

Comment: What logic did you use to get row `0         d             0.3176` ? because looking at your dataset, it looks like it just randomly happened based on the sorting of the `importance` column. I don't see a deterministic sorting, so results might be different from run to run

Comment: Id expect your results to have items `(0,a,0),(0,b,0),(0,c,0),(0,d,0),(1,a,0),(1,b,0),(1,c,0),(1,d,0)....` bacause you said:

 > Now, using this dataframe I want to align **each** value of importance column with **each** element of labels and features arrays`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you example there isn't enough information for me have a deterministic solution. Since spark is distributed processing engine, you would need to have a deterministic way to sort the `importance` dataframe to achieve the result you need.

I believe change of the approach is needed to get the output you want:

1. `CROSS JOIN` `label` and `feature` into `labelFeatureDs`
2. Add a column `rownumber` based on the sorting you need to `labelFeatureDs` (in your example sorting is by `label` then `feature`)
3. Add `rownumber` to `importance` based on whichever sorting you have here
4. `INNER JOIN` `importance` to `labelFeatureDs` on `rownumber`

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", true)

val importanceDf = Seq(
(0.0  ),
(0.0  ),
(0.0  ),
(0.317),
(0.0  ),
(0.0  ),
(-0.78),
(-0.37),
(0.0  ),
(0.0  ),
(0.0  ),
(0.0  )
).
toDF("importance").
select(col("*"), row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(lit(null)).orderBy(lit(null))).as("rn"))
importanceDf.show

val labelsDf = Seq(0,1,2).toDF("label")
val featuresDf = Seq("a","b","c","d").toDF("feature")

val labelFeatureDs = labelsDf.join(featuresDf).sort($"label", $"feature").select(col("*"), row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(lit(null)).orderBy(lit(null))).as("rn"))
labelFeatureDs.show

val result = labelFeatureDs.join(importanceDf, "rn")
```

Result:

```
scala> result.show
+---+-----+-------+----------+
| rn|label|feature|importance|
+---+-----+-------+----------+
|  1|    0|      a|       0.0|
|  2|    0|      b|       0.0|
|  3|    0|      c|       0.0|
|  4|    0|      d|     0.317|
|  5|    1|      a|       0.0|
|  6|    1|      b|       0.0|
|  7|    1|      c|     -0.78|
|  8|    1|      d|     -0.37|
|  9|    2|      a|       0.0|
| 10|    2|      b|       0.0|
| 11|    2|      c|       0.0|
| 12|    2|      d|       0.0|
+---+-----+-------+----------+
```